# How to write an sql query to update multiple columns of a table using prepared statements?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have been trying some thing like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatment("UPDATE table_nm(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) SET(?,?,?,?,?)");

ps.setString(1, textField1.getText());
ps.setString(2, textField2.getText());
ps.setString(3, textField3.getText());
ps.setString(4, textField4.getText());
ps.setString(5, textField5.getText());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

May i know what am i doing wrong here. I tried different ways, but none are working. I just want to update all the columns.

Comment: Learn basic sql. Your syntax is outright wrong. `UPDATE table SET field1=value1, field2=value2, field3=value3, etc`

Comment: i tried this too but its'nt updating.

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatment("UPDATE table_nm SET col2=?, col3=?, col4=?, col5=? WHERE col1=?");

Comment: It is not updating means what? Any error? Show error stack.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was There was no row inserted, i thought updating will automatically add the row. Thanks for the help. Its working when i inserted a row and perform the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
("UPDATE COFFEES SET col1 = ? , col2 =? , col3 =?  and So on .....")
```

FyI, You can also add where caluse like this `WHERE col1 LIKE ?");`

```
 PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatment("UPDATE table_nm SET col1 = ? , col2 =? , col3 =? ")

  ps.setString(1, textField1.getText());
  ps.setString(2, textField2.getText());
  ps.setString(3, textField2.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MarcB, the `UPDATE` statement in your code is wrong:

Change:

```
UPDATE table_nm(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) SET(?,?,?,?,?)
```

To:

```
UPDATE table_nm 
   SET col1=?, col2=?, col3=?, col4=?, col5=?
```

Rest of your code seem to be fine.

**Refer to**:
[**MySQL:  UPDATE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)